# drawing 1.0.1 not working

Tags: installed-programs

I often use drawing application.

Since a few days the app doesn't start.
I have Ubuntu 22.
I tried to uninstall and re-install the app via snap, but, even after that, nothing happens when I start the app.
Here is my terminal output.

```
user@user-All-Series:~$ sudo snap install drawing
[sudo] password di user: 
drawing 1.0.1 da Ken VanDine è stato installato
user@user-All-Series:~$ drawing &
[1] 212365
user@user-All-Series:~$ /snap/drawing/27/gnome-platform/command-chain/desktop-launch: /snap/drawing/27/usr/bin/drawing: /snap/gnome-42-2204-sdk/current/usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/snap/drawing/27/gnome-platform/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 603: /snap/drawing/27/usr/bin/drawing: Success
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you,
Andrea

Comment: Ubuntu 22, so you're using Ubuntu Core 22 ?  (*22 & 22.04 are different Ubuntu products; the different format highlights differences between them*)

Comment: In case this is an issue; I've reported it here - https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/drawing-snap-not-working/13669/22  (*I don't have time currently to test for it; so reported using text from this page only*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem with the Gnome Drawing app, but I found the solution. Installing `gnome-42-2204-sdk` solves this as it provides the necessarily libraries needed for gnome 42 apps. I don't know why the dependency doesn't come installed with drawing when updating snaps.

https://snapcraft.io/install/gnome-42-2204-sdk/ubuntu

> Shared GNOME 42 Ubuntu stack
>
> This snap contains only the necessary libraries required by GNOME
> applications.

Install it by typing:

```
sudo snap install gnome-42-2204-sdk
```